# Телеграмм бот Python aiogram3 не могу реализовать отправку сообщения в случае не нажатия на инлайн кнопку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, таймер, inline

Не знаю как это реализовать в случае не нажатия инлай кнопки

```
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

scheduler.add_job(send_message_time_start, trigger='date',
                      run_date=datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10),
                      kwargs={'bot': bot})
scheduler.start()

async def send_message_time_start(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    url ='https://www'
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, url)
```

Вот сама кнопка

```
async def get_start(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    photo = FSInputFile('notphoto.jpg')
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id,photo,caption=f'Привет {message.from_user.first_name}. Хочешь научиться!',
                         reply_markup=inline_keyboard_start())

def inline_keyboard_start():
keyboard_builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
keyboard_builder.button(text='Получить уроки!', callback_data='_1url_')

keyboard_builder.adjust(1)
return keyboard_builder.as_markup()
```